# How to sort time column in jsgrid?

Tags: jsgrid

We are binding a table using jqgrid. We have the first column start as a time column with a 12-hour format. We are facing an issue with sorting this data. The data is sorted correctly but it is not taking am/pm into consideration. Below is our code for binding the jqgrid:

```
var newFieldsArray =
        [
            { name: "ID", title: "ID", type: "number", width: "50px", visible: false },
            {
                name: "TimeStart", title: "Start", type: "customTime", width: "100px", validate: "required",
                sorttype: "date",
                formatter : {     
                    date : {       
                    AmPm : ["am","pm","AM","PM"],       
                    }     
                },
                // datefmt: "m/d/Y h:i A",
                //sorttype: 'datetime', formatter: 'date', formatoptions: {newformat: 'd/m/y', srcformat: 'Y-m-d H:i:s'},
                insertTemplate: function () {
                    var $result = jsGrid.fields.customTime.prototype.insertTemplate.call(this); // original input

                    $result.val(varendTime);

                    return $result;
                },
                itemTemplate: function (value, item) {
                    return "<b style='display:none'>" + Date.parse(item.StartDate) + "</b><span>" + (item.TimeStart) + "</span>";
                }
            },
            {
                name: "TimeEnd", title: "End", type: "customTime", width: "100px", validate: "required",sorttype: "date", datefmt: "h:i"
            },
            { name: "TimeTotal", title: "Time", type: "text", width: "50px", readOnly: true },
            {
                name: "CoilPO", title: "Coil PO", type: "text", width: "50px", validate: "required",
                insertTemplate: function () {
                    var $result = jsGrid.fields.text.prototype.insertTemplate.call(this); // original input

                    $result.val(varlot);

                    return $result;
                }
            },
            { name: "Joints", title: "Joints", type: "integer", width: "60px" },
            { name: "CommercialGrade", title: "Commercial Grade", type: "integer", width: "80px" },
            { name: "QAHold", title: "QA Hold", type: "integer", width: "60px" },
            { name: "Rejected", title: "Reject", type: "integer", width: "60px" },
            { name: "ActionTaken", title: "Reason of Delay / Action Taken", type: "text", width: "120px" },
            {
                name: "ClassId", title: "Class",
                type: "select", items: classDataArr,//classData.filter(function(n){return classdt.indexOf(n.Id) != -1 }),//classData,
                valueField: "Id", textField: "Title",
                insertTemplate: function () {
                    debugger;
                    var taxCategoryField = this._grid.fields[12];
                    var $insertControl = jsGrid.fields.select.prototype.insertTemplate.call(this);

                    var classId = 0;
                    var taxCategory = $.grep(voiceData, function (team) {
                        return (team.ClassId) === classId && (team.StationId) == parseInt($('#ddlEquipmentName').val());
                    });
                    taxCategoryField.items = taxCategory;
                    $(".tax-insert").empty().append(taxCategoryField.insertTemplate());

                    $insertControl.on("change", function () {
                        debugger;
                        var classId = parseInt($(this).val());
                        var taxCategory = $.grep(voiceData, function (team) {
                            return (team.ClassId) === classId && (team.StationId) == parseInt($('#ddlEquipmentName').val());
                        });
                        taxCategoryField.items = taxCategory;
                        $(".tax-insert").empty().append(taxCategoryField.insertTemplate());
                    });

                    return $insertControl;
                },
                editTemplate: function (value) {
                    var taxCategoryField = this._grid.fields[12];
                    var $editControl = jsGrid.fields.select.prototype.editTemplate.call(this, value);

                    var changeCountry = function () {
                        var classId = parseInt($editControl.val());
                        var taxCategory = $.grep(voiceData, function (team) {
                            return (team.ClassId) === classId && (team.StationId) == parseInt($('#ddlEquipmentName').val());
                        });
                        taxCategoryField.items = taxCategory;
                        $(".tax-edit").empty().append(taxCategoryField.editTemplate());
                    };
                    debugger;
                    $editControl.on("change", changeCountry);
                    changeCountry();
                    return $editControl;
                }
            },
            {
                name: "VoiceId", title: "Voice", type: "select", items: voiceData,
                valueField: "Id", textField: "Title", width: "120px", validate: "required",
                insertcss: "tax-insert",
                editcss: "tax-edit",
                itemTemplate: function (teamId) {
                    var t = $.grep(voiceData, function (team) { return team.Id === teamId; })[0].Title;
                    return t;
                },
            },
            { name: "Remarks", title: "Remarks", type: "text", width: "110px" },
            { name: "control", type: "control" }
        ];

    hoursGrid.jsGrid("option", "fields", newFieldsArray);
```

Below is two screenshots of data that appear when we sort:
[image: Ascending]

[image: Descending]

Can someone tell me what we are doing wrong?

Comment: Please, correct your tag and your Title - you use jsGrid and not jqGrid - that are different libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing up jsGrid and jqGrid. The way to achieve it in jsGrid is using the built-in sorter `jsGrid.sortStrategies.date`, I added an example below.

As commented by @Tomy Tomov (the creator of jqGrid), you're using jsGrid, not jqGrid. This is evident both by your code and by the UI in the screenshot.

Specifically, you took the date sorter of jqGrid and used it in your jsGrid code, but (of course) it's not supported there. You can go ahead and look in [jsGrid source](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsgrid/1.5.3/jsgrid.js) for `AmPm` which you used - and see it's not there.

So how to do it in jsGrid?

Just pass the built-in sorter `jsGrid.sortStrategies.date` to the `sorter` property. However, it does require `Date` objects, so if you only got time strings, you'll have to convert those to dates.

Below is a quick demo ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cdozunhs/)), click the date column title to sort:

- Note that `getData` gets a function parameter that is responsible to get all data as `Date` objects, and that the value of `isUTC` depends on whether you actually use it

  ```js
  $(document).ready(function () {
      const dataFunc = getDataTimes;
      $("#jsGrid").jsGrid({
          width: "100%",
          data: getData(dataFunc),
          sorting: true,
          fields: [{ 
            name: "name",
            type: "text", 
            width: 50 
          }, { 
            name: "date", 
            type: "date", 
            width: 50, 
            sorter: jsGrid.sortStrategies.date, 
            cellRenderer: (value, item) => {
              const withYear = false;
              const isUTC = dataFunc == getDataTimes;
              return renderDateTime(value, item, withYear, isUTC);
            }
          }
        ]
      });
  });

  function getData(getDates) {
    const data = [
      {name: "a"}, {name: "b"}, {name: "c"},
      {name: "d"}, {name: "e"}, {name: "f"},
    ];
    const dates = getDates();
    for (let i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
      data[i].date = dates[i];
    }
    return data;
  }

  function getDataDates() {
    const date1 = new Date(2022, 10, 1, 4, 50);
    const date2 = new Date(2022, 10, 1, 8, 50);   
    const date3 = new Date(2022, 10, 1, 15, 50);  
    const date4 = new Date(2021, 10, 1, 4, 50);
    const date5 = new Date(2021, 10, 1, 8, 50);
    const date6 = new Date(2021, 10, 1, 15, 50);
    return [date1, date2, date3, date4, date5, date6];
  }

  function getDataTimes() {
    const time1 = "3:50 AM";
    const time2 = "8:50 AM";
    const time3 = "4:50 AM";
    const time4 = "3:50 PM";
    const time5 = "8:50 PM";
    const time6 = "4:50 PM";
    const times = [time1, time2, time3, time4, time5, time6];
    return times.map(t => convertTime12to24(t));
  }

  function convertTime12to24(time12h) {
    const [time, modifier] = time12h.split(' ');
    let [hours, minutes] = time.split(':');
    if (modifier === 'PM') {
      hours = parseInt(hours, 10) + 12;
    }
    return new Date(Date.UTC(2022,0,1,hours, minutes));
  }

  function renderDateTime(value, row, withYear, isUTC) {
    return `<td>${getDateTimeAsString(value, withYear, isUTC)}</td>`;
  }

  function getDateTimeAsString(date, withYear, isUTC) {
    var options = {
      hour: 'numeric', 
      minute: 'numeric', 
      hour12: true
    };
    if (withYear) {
      options.withYear = 'numeric';
    }
    if (isUTC) {
      options.timeZone = 'UTC';
    }
    return date.toLocaleString('en-US', options);
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsgrid/1.5.3/jsgrid.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsgrid/1.5.3/jsgrid-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsgrid/1.5.3/jsgrid.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <div id="jsGrid" class="jsgrid"></div>
  ```

Comment: Hi OfirD, is it possible without year in the date? As you can see in my example above, we don't have that available.

Comment: @lovethakker I assume what you actually mean is that you don't have `Date` objects as data, but plain strings which are just time of day. In that case, you should first convert those strings to date objects. I edited my snippet to demonstrate how it's done in `getDataTimes`.

Comment: @lovethakker please see the updated snippet with `getDataTimes`. Is that what you need?

Answer (score 0):

Let me give it a try, we have 2 options to perform Sorting operation in JsGrid:
1.Custom Field (Topic Name you can refer below link)
Reference Link :http://js-grid.com/docs/#grid-fields

In this, you can define custom property in your config and extend it.
You can use sorter property and call your user defined function werein you can logic to sort date with time stamps directly.

2.Sorting Strategies (Topic Name you can refer below link)
Reference Link :http://js-grid.com/docs/#grid-fields

In this, you can create your custom objects and then apply sorting strategies of date directly on to the object to perform sorting operation as per your logic.